# Yii2:Saving listbox multi-select field to db

Tags: php, listbox, yii2

I am created a listbox and related functions like in my model Appointment.php

**Validation Rule & related function in Appointment.php**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [            
            ['weekdays', 'validateWeekDays'],

        ];
    }

public static function getWeekdaysList()
        {
            return [
                'monday' => 'Monday',
                'tuesday' => 'Tuesday',
                'wednesday' => 'Wednesday',
                'thursday' => 'Thursday',
                'friday' => 'Friday',
                'saturday' => 'Saturday',
                'sunday' => 'Sunday',
            ];
        }
    public function validateWeekdays ($attribute, $params)
        {
            $label = '«' . $this->getAttributeLabel($attribute) . '»';

            // Checking if it's array first
            if (is_array(!$this->$attribute)) {    
                $this->addError($attribute, "$label must be array.");

                return;
            }

            $allowedWeekdays = array_keys(static::getWeekdayslist());

            // Checking if every selection is in list of allowed values
            foreach ($this->$attribute as $weekday) 
            {
                if (!in_array($weekday, $allowedWeekdays)) {
                    $this->addError($attribute, "$label - $weekday is not in allowed list");
                }
            }
```

**Then in my _form.php**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'weekdays')->listBox(app\models\Appointment::getWeekdaysList(), [
    'multiple' => true,
    'size' => 7,
]) ?>
```

Now while saving the form I am getting the error like:
**Database Exception – yii\db\Exception**

```
PDOStatement::bindValue() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given
Failed to prepare SQL: INSERT INTO `appointment` (`appointment_id`,
`appointment_date`, 
 `patient_detail_id`, `patient_name`, 
`priority`, `doctor_name`, `doctor_fee`, 
`discount`, `weekdays`, `total_amount`, 
`is_paid`, `hospital_commission`) VALUES 
(:qp0, :qp1, :qp2, :qp3, :qp4, :qp5, 
:qp6, :qp7, :qp8, :qp9, :qp10, :qp11)
```

What I need to do to correct this error. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use `Json::encode()` to save the array as a json string, which is nice for complicated arrays.

Comment: Hi deacs, can you please elaborate on that, how can I do that.

Comment: Hi deacs I am facing a small issue as on update the saved values are not highlighted in the listbox as Saved. Any solution?

Comment: 1 sec, I'll post a solution for you as an answer

Comment: You don't need `validateWeekdays`, you can simply use `in` validator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok all I needed was one function and it works perfectly.

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
        {       
        $weekday = implode(",", $this->weekdays);
        $this->weekdays = $weekday;
        return parent::beforeSave($insert);
        }
```

In the controller update action I have added the line

```
$model->weekdays = explode(',', $model->weekdays);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try serializing your array before saving it to the database field (which should be a `VARCHAR`):

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) 
    {
        $this->weekdays = serialize($this->weekdays);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then unserializing when fetching it again:

```
public function afterFind()
{
    parent::afterFind();
    $this->weekdays = unserialize($this->weekdays);
}
```

And make sure you have an array again when you render your form. You could do the same with `yii\helpers\Json::encode()` and `yii\helpers\Json::decode()`.

Comment: Hi deacs, when creating a new record with your code - I am getting the error like - `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: it is line 96 - `public static function encode($content, $doubleEncode = true)
    {
        return htmlspecialchars($content, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, Yii::$app ? Yii::$app->charset : 'UTF-8', $doubleEncode);
    }`

Comment: which lines of code that you or I wrote caused the error?

Comment: Ok I will check line by line & revert.

Comment: Ok on insert part there is no error, but I am getting the value like - a:2:{i:0;s:6:"friday";i:1;s:8:"saturday";}. so it is the unserialize part which is causing the error. As when I am adding the afterfind() I am getting the error.

Comment: OK deacs - I think I found the solution with your suggestion - please suggest if that is correct - In the insert part I stayed with my code and in the update part I have added this line in my controller which at the time being looks fine  $model->weekdays = explode(',', $model->weekdays)